# Across function for time difference

Tags: r

I use this example:

```
df <- data.frame(start = c("2016-09-30 00:00:00", "2016-09-30 00:00:00", "2016-09-30 00:00:00"),  end = c("2017-03-12 00:00:00", "2017-06-30 00:00:00", "2017-12-01 00:00:00"))
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ymd_hms),
           diff = as.numeric(difftime(end, start, units = 'days')))
```

However I receive this error:

```
Error in across(everything(), ymd_hms) : could not find function "across"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your example works for me. Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the tidyverse? `across` is a pretty new function. You'll need `dplyr` package version 1.0 or above

Comment: worked for me as well.. my guess is packages overlap.. restart R/ detach all packages.. then try the exact same code.. with only two libraries mentioned above

Comment: Unless there is any other package that has a function called exactly `mutate` and you have loaded it after loading `dplyr` it should work. You may also have (accidentally) skipped the line `library(dplyr)` (happens to me very often)

Comment: You should update your `dplyr` package. That's the only possible problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `dplyr::` to mutate

```
df <- data.frame(start = c("2016-09-30 00:00:00", "2016-09-30 00:00:00", "2016-09-30 00:00:00"),  end = c("2017-03-12 00:00:00", "2017-06-30 00:00:00", "2017-12-01 00:00:00"))
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), ymd_hms),
         diff = as.numeric(difftime(end, start, units = 'days')))
```

Comment: `dplyr::` is not needed in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution as a safe alternative:

```
library(lubridate)

DF %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ymd_hms(.x)), 
         diff = interval(start, end) / days(1))

       start        end diff
1 2016-09-30 2017-03-12  163
2 2016-09-30 2017-06-30  273
3 2016-09-30 2017-12-01  427
```